How should I fix this Vercel deployment error?
Getting this error while trying to deploy on vercel.
WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings
> Installing Builder: @frontity/now
WARN! npm WARN deprecated @now/node-bridge@1.3.1: "@now/node-bridge" is deprecated and will stop receiving updates January 2021. Please use "@vercel/node-bridge" instead.

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at module.exports (/vercel/path0/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/vercel/path0/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/vercel/path0/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

i tried lots of formulas , updating dependencies, etc..

Deprecated Dependency May be try with npm install @vercel/node-bridge, npx frontity clean & npx frontity build
